# Define variable based on concatenated PostgreSQL output in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I am trying to generate a PHP variable that can be used to generate select options on a website.

The php is currently as follows:

```
$sql_names = pg_query($dbconn, "SELECT id, name external_name FROM names);
    if (!$sql_names) {
      echo "Er\n";
      exit;
    }

    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($sql_names)) foreach($row as $a => $b){ $name_options = '<option value="' . $row[0] . '">' . $row[1] . '</option>';}
```

This is then called later on as follows:

```
<select name="NAMES[]">
        <?php echo $name_options; ?>
</select>
```

However it only returns 1 option when there should be 6.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are not append the results in the  $name_options variable. This way you are returning only the last row.
Try this:

```
$sql_names = pg_query($dbconn, "SELECT id, name external_name FROM names);
if (!$sql_names) {
    echo "Er\n";
    exit;
}
$name_options = ""; 
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($sql_names)){ 
    $name_options .= '<option value="' . $row[0] . '">' . $row[1] . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: This almost worked, but it ended up returning 5 of each row! Solution seems to be: `$sql_names = pg_query($dbconn, "SELECT id, name external_name FROM names);
if (!$sql_names) {
    echo "Er\n";
    exit;
}
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($sql_names))      
    $name_options .= '<option value="' . $row[0] . '">' . $row[1] . '</option>';
` Just needed to get rid of the foreach!

Comment: Yes, I see it. I edited the answer but I think you could do that. Regards.